# Regex for Java version number

Tags: regex

I've a regex as follows:

```
(?!\.)(\d+(\.\d+)+)(?![\d\.])$
```

It valids strings as: `1.0.0` (software version).

How could I edit it in order to valid as well the following string?

- `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`
- `1.0.0.RC`
- `1.0.0-RELEASE`

An alphanumeric string could follows the version number, but only if there is a `.` or `-` (just one).

Comment: I've edited my regex... Do take a look

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a non-capturing group for `.[A-Z]+` or `-[A-Z]+` part and make it as optional.

```
(?!\.)(\d+(\.\d+)+)(?:[-.][A-Z]+)?(?![\d.])$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yO3sT9/1)

If you want to capture the string part(*Uppercase letters preceded by a dot or hyphen*) then make the non-capturing group to capturing group.

```
(?!\.)(\d+(\.\d+)+)([-.][A-Z]+)?(?![\d.])$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yO3sT9/2)

To capture and strore only the letters into separate group.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yO3sT9/3)

```
(?!\.)(\d+(\.\d+)+)(?:[-.]([A-Z]+))?(?![\d.])$
```

Comment: What difference does (?!\.) make to the string? Does it only bear relevance when $ is used?

Comment: it asserts that the number which is going to be matched should not preceeded by a dot

Comment: And yet in https://regex101.com/r/yO3sT9/1 when adding e.g  .1.0.0-SNAPSHOT, the text still forms part of the match (even though the number was preceded by "."?

Answer (score 2):

Just use this less complicated regex

```
/(\d.){2}\d(?=((-|\.)[A-Z]+)|$)/g
```

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/lW9jQ3/3)

Answer (score 0):

```
^\d+\.\d+\.\d+[\.\-]?[A-Z]*$
```

for java replace "\" to "\\"

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone need to capture each component of a semantic version this regex will help do this:

```
^(\d+)(?:\.(\d+)(?:\.(\d+))?)?(?:[-.]([A-Z]+))?(?![\d.])$
```

The ***major*** will be captured in the group 1, the ***minor*** in group 2, the ***incremental*** in group 3 and the ***qualifier*** in the group 4.