# regex to extract software version

Tags: java, regex, version

I tried with this regex `(?!\\.)(\\d+(\\.\\d+)+)([-.][a-zA-Z]+)?(?![\\d.])` using Java code to extract software version number form short text as following:

```
... Dashbuilder before 0.6.0.Beta allows remote  ... another version 0.6.1 which ...
```

However, I can extract `0.6.0` and `0.6.1` only without the letters Beta.

**Update**
Sometimes, the software version comes with digits and characters. How could I update my regex to be able to extract software versions such as digits with letters (`0.6.0.beta`), or digits only (`0.6.1`),
Also, what if I want to extract the term `before` if it is preceding the version number using regex?

Comment: The shortest version I could find: `\d[^\s]+` - https://regex101.com/r/pW8gO5/5 - EDIT: `\d[^ ]+` works too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
((?:\d.)+)
```

**Test String**

```
... Dashbuilder before 0.6.0.Beta allows remote  ...
```

**Match Information**

```
MATCH 1
1.  [23-29] `0.6.0.`
```

DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/pW8gO5/1

---

**EDIT**

To extract `before 0.6.0.Beta` use:

```
(\b\w+\s(?:\d.)+\w+\b)
```

**Test String**

```
... Dashbuilder before 0.6.0.Beta allows remote  ...
```

**Match Information**

```
MATCH 1
1.  [16-33] `before 0.6.0.Beta`
```

DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/pW8gO5/2

---

**EDIT 2**

You can use `?` to match optional `before` word:

```
((?:before)?\s(?:\d.)+\w+\b)
```

**Test String**

```
... Dashbuilder before 0.6.0.Beta allows remote  ...

... Dashbuilder 0.6.0.Beta allows remote  ...
```

**Match Information**

```
MATCH 1
1.  [16-33] `before 0.6.0.Beta`
MATCH 2
1.  [69-80] ` 0.6.0.Beta`
```

DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/pW8gO5/3

---

**EDIT 3**

Updated to match the version too.

```
((?:before)?\s(?:[\d.])+[\w-]+)\b
```

**Test String**

```
... Dashbuilder before 0.6.0.Alpha allows remote  ...
... Dashbuilder before 0.6.0.Beta allows remote  ...
... Dashbuilder before 0.6.0.Beta allows remote  ...
... Dashbuilder before 0.6.0 allows remote  ...
... Dashbuilder before 0.6.0.SNAPSHOT allows remote  ...
... Dashbuilder before 0.6.0.RC allows remote  ...
... Dashbuilder before 0.6.0-RELEASE allows remote  ...
```

**Match Information**

```
MATCH 1
1.  [16-34] `before 0.6.0.Alpha`
MATCH 2
1.  [70-87] `before 0.6.0.Beta`
MATCH 3
1.  [123-140]   `before 0.6.0.Beta`
MATCH 4
1.  [176-188]   `before 0.6.0`
MATCH 5
1.  [224-245]   `before 0.6.0.SNAPSHOT`
MATCH 6
1.  [281-296]   `before 0.6.0.RC`
MATCH 7
1.  [332-352]   `before 0.6.0-RELEASE`
```

DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/pW8gO5/4

Comment: I want to extract before 0.6.0.Beta not only 0.6.0

Comment: @Sultan see EDIT 2

Comment: @Sultan This regex will extract any word that's preceding the version number. However if you want to find only word `before` than we would have to update the logic accordingly.

Comment: @Sultan but there should be a criteria by which we differentiate the word preceding the version with other words. Do you have any criteria to differentiate?

Comment: This is my question, it is simply if the word is before, then take it with the version, if not then just extract the version number and its letters (if any). 
Your regex solve the problem partially.

Comment: @Sultan see **EDIT 2**

Comment: What if the version does not have character? your regex will still extract characters. For example, if text has only '0.6.0', the regex will continue extract characters after the version number !!

Comment: I'm still saying the same thing. Do you have a pattern regarding what version name will follow? Are you sure that everytime it would be word `Beta` or can it change?

Comment: The word beta can be change, not always beta. 
I found this question posted one year ago (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26202439/regex-for-java-version-number) but the the regex does not work on my case !!

Comment: @Sultan see **EDIT 3**

Comment: Finally !! IT WORKS THANK YOU VERY MUCH